# (Node JS + Express) How do I render a file that is inside /views/subfolder/?

Tags: node.js, express

This seems like a pretty simple problem with Node JS + Express to resolve and I've done some research to resolve my issues but it came out didn't so I am here posting question!

All I am trying to do is render .ejs file from my routes. Just like any other basic Node JS app's file structure, my app is divided into

**/public , /views , /routes/ ,node_modules , app.js , package.json**

Inside my **app.js** , I have declared

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/views'));
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Inside my **/views** I have subfolders called **/characters** and **/series**
So it looks like **/views/characters/sample.ejs**

Now in my routes I have this **('ejs' has been declared as view engine in app.js)**,

```
app.get('/series' , function(req,res){

    res.render('series/some');


});
```

**Problem:** Before I moved **some.ejs** file into **/series** ,

```
res.render('some');
```

worked perfectly.But after moving the file into **/series** I've realized Node JS can't render (well..can't find the **some.ejs** file).I could just remove all the sub folders and just drop all **.ejs** files under */views* but it would be messy.

**PS. I've tried passing multiple directories under **app.js** attempts.**

for example:

```
app.set('views', [path.join(__dirname, '/views'),path.join(__dirname, 
'/views/characters/'), path.join(__dirname, '/views/series/')]);
```

File Structure:

```
           /myapp
                ->/node_modules
                ->/public
                    ->/css
                    ->/fonts
                    ->/images
                    ->/js
                    ->/template
                     ->/video
                ->/routes
                     ->characters.js
                     ->etc.js
                     ->index.js
                     ->series.js

                ->/views
                      ->/characters
                         ->characters_index.ejs
                      ->/series
                         ->series_index.ejs
                      ->index.ejs
              ->app.js
              ->package.json
```

This the structure. So I want to render either **series_index.ejs** or **characters_index.ejs**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">

  <head>
      <title><% include ../public/template/title %></title>

       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <% include ../public/template/scripts %>


    </head>

    <body id="series_body">

    <% include ../public/template/background_effect %>


<% include ../public/template/navigation_bar %>

 <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row content-fluid">


        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 " >
            <div id="series_description" class="content-fluid">
        <h2>Batman (1989)</h2>
        <a href="/series/batman" ><img  class="img-responsive" 
     src="http://localhost:3000/images/series/batman_1989.jpg" width="200px" 
    height="300px"/></a>
            </div>

             <div id="series_description" class="content-fluid">
        <h2>Batman and Robin (1997)</h2>
        <a href="/series/batman_and_robin"><img  class="img-responsive" 
      src="http://localhost:3000/images/series/batman_and_robin.png" 
   width="200px" height="300px"/></a>
            </div>

             <div id="series_description" class="content-fluid">
        <h2>The Dark Knight Rises (2012)</h2>
        <a href="/series/the_dark_knight_rises"><img  class="img-responsive" 
     src="http://localhost:3000/images/series/the_dark_knight_rises.jpg" 
   width="200px" height="300px"/></a>
            </div>

        </div>

         <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 " >

           <div id="series_description" class="content-fluid">
        <h2>Batman Returns (1992)</h2>
        <a href="/series/batman_returns"><img class="img-responsive" 
      src="http://localhost:3000/images/series/batman_returns.png" 
   width="200px" height="300px"/></a>
            </div>

             <div id="series_description" class="content-fluid"> 
        <h2>Batman Begins (2005)</h2>
        <a href="/series/batman_begins"><img  class="img-responsive" 
      src="http://localhost:3000/images/series/batman_begins.jpg" 
    width="200px" height="300px"/></a>
            </div>

        </div>

         <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 " >

           <div id="series_description" class="content-fluid">
        <h2>Batman Forever (1995)</h2>
        <a href="/series/batman_forever"><img  class="img-responsive" 
    src="http://localhost:3000/images/series/batman_forever.png" 
   width="200px" height="300px"/></a>
            </div>

             <div id="series_description" class="content-fluid">
        <h2>The Dark Knight (2008)</h2>
        <a href="/series/the_dark_knight"><img  class="img-responsive" 
    src="http://localhost:3000/images/series/the_dark_knight.jpg" 
  width="200px" height="300px"/></a>
            </div>

        </div>

     </div>

  </div>    

  <% include ../public/template/footer %>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the problem is lying in your slashes, try setting this array of views:

```
    app.set('views', [path.join(__dirname, 'views'),
                      path.join(__dirname, 'views/characters/'), 
                      path.join(__dirname, 'views/series/')]);
```

then just call your view normally:
`res.render('some');`

you can check your mounted view folder by:
`app.get('views');`

Comment: Hi Jakub. I just tried and it's still the same. So for curiosity I did **console.log(app.get('views'));**  . The paths are all correctly set it up but strangely it still can't find 'some'...

Comment: Can you provide this log, and full structure(with extensions) of your project?

Comment: I edited my question by adding file structure with extensions, please check it out.

Comment: can you try setting up app.js file in this order: views->view engine->express static?

Comment: app.set('views', [path.join(__dirname, 'views'),
                    path.join(__dirname, 'views/characters/'), 
                    path.join(__dirname, 'views/series/')]);
app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

Comment: still no effect.. :(

Comment: Tried on my project and refactored views model - all working. In this case I would look at engine /execution itself to search for some abbreviations

Comment: one more thing - do you have any included partials in your views itself?

Comment: What exactly do you mean about "engine /execution" Jakub? well views folder only contains .ejs files and each .ejs files has template and scripts but I don't think the contents of .ejs matters.

Comment: It could - if in your ejs file you do include another ejs files/etc. when moving file to another directory, you should change paths in files itself - can you show me your ejs file?

Comment: I added series_index.ejs into my question please refer to it.

Comment: Knew it, you have: <% include ../public/template/title %>, but with this setting, you are going 1 directory app, so you are searching for title file in views folder, not in the template folder. You have to change all occurrences of ../ to ../../ in your files in new directory

Comment: OMG You're a life saver man! I really appreciate your help. It's working smoothly. So now I learned that even the content of  ejs file matters.

Comment: This will not work if we have 'views' files with same name under different directories.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didn't work for me, so I found a way that did the job.

I don't know for the OP, but when I tried to render a view held in a subdirectory, I was getting a:

`ENOENT: no such file or directory`.

The real issue was the **layout path**!

I was using a layout so my index file had a "extends layouts/main" at the top ;

**this was the root cause of the error!**

As the rendered view is located deeper in the directory structure, I needed to change the culprit to "extends ../layouts/main".

After having done this modification and restarted my node server, everything was fine!

Hope this helps some of you guys!